# Flutter: Row is stepping a line inside a Wrap

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

suppose we have:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text('a'),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Text('b'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

the output of this would be:
[image: the output of this would be]

notice how each of the `Row`'s is taking a whole line

how can I fix this and make them side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wrap your `Row`'s with `FittedBox`, which will make them only consume the space they need, so your code should be like this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        FittedBox(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text('a'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        FittedBox(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text('b'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and your output will be like this:
[image: and your output will be like this]